# PuPHPet with Amazon - Ubuntu 14.04 and PHP 5.6

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, vagrant, puphpet, vagrant-provision

The tool https://puphpet.com/ gives you a GUI for Vagrant config files. Besides that it can be used to spin up Servers on AWS using Vagrant. It's pretty nice, since you can write a config file and have Vagrant and Puppet handle the rest.

The only "problem" I have with it, is that there's only Ubuntu 12.04 available for Amazon and furthermore only PHP 5.5 is supported for installation through Puppet. I would like to have an Ubuntu 14.04 Server with PHP 5.6.
Is there a way to achive this throu PuPHPet, can I just alter the config files? If yes, what config file do I have to adjust and what settings?

What I found so far is, that in the file `./puphpet/config.yaml` there is a line at

```
vagrantfile:
    vm:
        provider:
            aws:
                ami: ami-0df6d77a
```

Which is pointing according to http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04.2/release/ at an Ubuntu 12.02 image. can I just switch it with an ami id from http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/14.04.3/release/ (that would be `ami-ab2f0fdc` for 64bit or `ami-ad2f0fda` for 32bit in my case) to spin up a Ubuntu 14.04 machine? And if yes, am I then able to just change the PHP version to 5.6 in the config file?

If it's to offtopic, please let me know, then I'll remove the question.

Comment: Seems logical.  Try it and let us know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

In the same file you found the ami for the aws machine to use, you'll get the configuration for everything, php is there too so make sure to change the version for the version you want

```
php:
    install: '1' <-- tells puppet to install, '0' to not install
    settings:
        version: '5.6'
```

for the ami this is correct. Just make sure it is set correctly in the `vagrantfile-aws` for the `aws.ami` parameter.

basically https://puphpet.com/ is a front end for all those parameters but its really to hard for them to keep on all possible values so just tweak what you want in the `config.yaml` and `vagrant up`!